# Cannot resolve symbol toJSONObject

Tags: java, json, compiler-errors, xml-to-json

So I was trying to convert an XML String to JSON, but I keep getting cannot resolve symbol toJSONObject

```
JSONObject job = new XML.toJSONObject(d2.toString());
```

I included the dependency,

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20171018</version>
</dependency>
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What is your import for `XML`?

Comment: import org.json.*; @RobinGreen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Remove `new` keyword**. Change

```
JSONObject job = new XML.toJSONObject(d2.toString());
```

to

```
JSONObject job = XML.toJSONObject(d2.toString());
```

Because `toJSONObject` is a static method that returns `JSONObject`